# jQuery post firing twice in Bootstrap site

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a Bootstrap site, so I have to put all of my jQuery at the bottom of the page, not in the head.  I've discovered on some reading that this can cause a behavior where jQuery events fire twice.  What is actually happening is that the clicks are accumulating.  So the first click, the event fires once, then the second click it fires twice and so on.  What is causing this behavior?

The way this script is intended to work is it is designed to toggle user notifications by running a PHP script.  That all works fine.  So when the user clicks the "subscribe" link, it subscribes them and the link is rewritten to be an "unsubscribe" link.  This may be where my problem is happening.  I'm just not sure how to work around this.  Anyway, if the user clicks the link again, it toggles back to "subscribe" and so on.  Here is my code.

I found a tip elsewhere that I can use `e.stopImmediatePropagation` to eliminate this behavior, but it's not working.

```
$('.subscription').bind('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         e.stopImmediatePropagation()

         var subscribe = jQuery(this).data('subscribe')
         var forumId = jQuery(this).data('id')
         var href = jQuery(this).data('href')
         var selector = jQuery(this)

         if (subscribe == 1) {
             $('#email-notifications').modal('show')
             $('.notify').on('click', function() {
                  var response = $(this).data('response')

                  if (response == 1) {
                      // subscribe the user
                      $.post('/discussion-boards/subscribe', { notify : response, forum : forumId }, function(data) {
                          // do nothing in the callback
                      });

                      // rewrite HTML and set subscription flag to 0
                      selector.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Unsubscribe from this Topic').data('subscribe', 0)
                  }
             });
         } else {
             $.post('/discussion-boards/unsubscribe', { forum : forumId }, function(data) {
                 // do nothing in the callback
             })

             // rewrite HTML and set subscription flag to 1;
             selector.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Subscribe to this Topic').data('subscribe', 1)
         }
     })
```

Comment: I should add that clicking the anchor tag with the `.subscription` class opens a modal where the value of notify is set by clicking a button.

Comment: does the `.notify` element get rebuild every time modal is called? if not it will have a click event handler attached to it for every click on `.subscription`.

Comment: If this is the issue, then there are plenty of approaches. 1. keep the code as is but check before adding the specific handler 2. modify the code in order to add the handler to `notify` out of the click handler of `subscription` 3. rebuilding the element somehow every time modal is called

Comment: OK, thanks, this should get me on the right path.

Comment: Got it working with number 1.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! Please post what you did and accept it, to assist others that may read this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is the final solution:

```
$('.subscription').on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         e.stopImmediatePropagation()

         var subscribe = jQuery(this).data('subscribe')
         var forumId = jQuery(this).data('id')
         var href = jQuery(this).data('href')
         var selector = jQuery(this)

         if (subscribe == 1) {
             $('#email-notifications').modal('show')
             $('.notify').unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
                  var response = $(this).data('response')

                  if (response == 1) {
                      // subscribe the user
                      $.post('/discussion-boards/subscribe', { notify : response, forum : forumId }, function(data) {
                          // do nothing in the callback
                      });

                      // rewrite HTML and set subscription flag to 0
                      selector.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Unsubscribe from this Topic').data('subscribe', 0)
                  }
             });
         } else {
             $.post('/discussion-boards/unsubscribe', { forum : forumId }, function(data) {
                 // do nothing in the callback
             })

             // rewrite HTML and set subscription flag to 1;
             selector.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Subscribe to this Topic').data('subscribe', 1)
         }
     })
```